# File.listFiles() conflicts with directory deletion

Tags: java, windows, java-io

Does `File.listFiles()` behave obtrusively in a directory? Does it hold file and/or directory handles? Does it `cd` into the directory?

One of my processes is calling Java's `File.listFiles()` on a directory, and another is trying to delete the same directory (e.g. using C#'s `Directory.Delete(DIRECTORY, true);`). The deletion is failing with "The directory is not empty" (which is a Windows error message). My suspicion is that the `File.listFiles()` is somehow getting in the way, although it's only performing a read operation.

NB: the Java process reads the directory recursively (if it finds subdirs, it reads those too). Thus, it's quite possible that the

`Directory.Delete(DIRECTORY, true)`

is in fact clashing with

`(new File(SUBDIRECTORY)).listFiles()`

Obviously the Java reader of SUBDIRECTORY is holding *some* kind of handle on SUBDIRECTORY. Would that prevent the deletion of the parent DIRECTORY?

Comment: It will vary from one OS to another, but Windows tends to lock more often than not, so I would assume that yes, `listFiles()` is getting a lock on the directory or sub-directories and preventing the deletion. You may want to reconsider your approach: why do you need a list of files from a directory that's about to be deleted? Is there something the Java process could be doing to delete the files instead? Maybe keeping an index of files instead of using `listFiles()` could work? Consider changing your design instead of trying to work around the error.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. The context is TeamCity (a continuous integration server). The Java process is a TeamCity plugin (outside of my control) that sniffs the disk for files with test results. The C# process is part of our "build" infrastructure (the continuous integration process itself).

Comment: So it sounds like the plugin is interfering with the build, then? As in this error occurs during the build? If so, it might be better to try and enter a bug against the plugin causing the issue to get them to fix it so it doesn't scan files of builds that are in progress.

Comment: Yes, I've done so [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-54771). I've also got to the bottom of it, more or less. I can now confirm that indeed `File.list()` can cause the deletion to break. As for your suggestion that the plugin wait until after the build, that won't do. The very purpose of the plugin is to detect & present the test results to the user in real time. In [my bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-54771) I included some workarounds, so I'm happy to move on now.

Comment: Good read on the bug report, and plus it gives more context to the question, which was helpful. Glad you found workarounds, though it seems like it will result in some tedious file management. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I have now confirmed that `File.list()` (but probably also `File.listFiles()`) *can* indeed cause this. See my comments above, as well as the gory details in the corresponding [TeamCity bug report](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-54771).